# Installing RAR package with PHP

Tags: php, apache, rar

I'm trying to install the rar package. I checked php.net's installation docs and it just said to execute `pecl -v install rar`

I did it and rebooted server but its still not working. I'm not very familiar with the Linux stuff so maybe did I do something wrong?

Phpinfo also display nothing about RAR package.

I'm trying to execute this script, I found it on php.net docs so it should be working:

```
$rar_arch = RarArchive::open('dl/test.rar');
if ($rar_arch === FALSE)
die("Could not open RAR archive.");

$rar_entries = $rar_arch->getEntries();
if ($rar_entries === FALSE)
die("Could retrieve entries.");

echo "Found " . count($rar_entries) . " entries.\n";

foreach ($rar_entries as $e) {
echo $e;
echo "\n";
}
$rar_arch->close();
```

Comment: Does this script output something?

Answer (score 2):

Answering this 4 year old question just because I had the same problem and I'm fairly new to the PHP/Apache/Pecl stack:

Basically, I followed this [guide](http://mewbies.com/how_to_enable_the_viewing_and_extracting_of_rar_files_on_your_webserver.htm). However, I have 2 versions of PHP installed and had to make some tweaks to make it work (also, update instructions to how PHP versions work as of 2018):

1. `sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev`
2. `pecl -v install rar`

RAR extension was installed on `/usr/lib/php/20131226`

3. Checked where were my extensions directory:

   ```
   php -i | grep extension
   extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20160303 => /usr/lib/php/20160303
   ```
4. Added a line on `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`

   ```
   extension=/usr/lib/php/20131226/rar.so
   ```
5. Then, restarted apache server as usual and everything worked fine!

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```