# can't Installing RAR extention with PHP 7.3

Tags: php, rar

I'm trying to install the rar package. I checked php.net's installation docs and it just said to execute pecl -v install rar

```
/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rararch.c:34: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define _GNU_SOURCE

/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rararch.c: In function ‘rararch_it_get_iterator’:
/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rararch.c:961:25: error: ‘zend_class_entry’ {aka ‘struct _zend_class_entry’} has no member named ‘iterator_funcs’; did you mean ‘iterator_funcs_ptr’?
  it->parent.funcs = ce->iterator_funcs.funcs;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         iterator_funcs_ptr
/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rararch.c: In function ‘minit_rararch’:
/tmp/pear/temp/rar/rararch.c:1173:18: error: ‘zend_class_entry’ {aka ‘struct _zend_class_entry’} has no member named ‘iterator_funcs’; did you mean ‘iterator_funcs_ptr’?
  rararch_ce_ptr->iterator_funcs.funcs = &rararch_it_funcs;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  iterator_funcs_ptr
make: *** [Makefile:198: rararch.lo] Error 1
rolling back 441 file operations
ERROR: `make' failed
```

how can install rar extension with php 7.3 on debian 10?

Comment: Maybe this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285306/installing-rar-package-with-php

Comment: @AmineKOUIS 
i saw this question but in second step when i want intall rar (in make step) got above error

Comment: Maybe update autoconf, make, and pecl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting comment from https://www.php.net/rar

> Officially it support only php 5.3 to 7.1.  With some luck it works on some 7.2 versions.
> The bug reports on the rar pecl-site aren't modified for years.
> I think this documentation on php.net should be removed, rar support is dead

Other way to do this:

```
shell_exec("unrar x $pathToRar $dirToExtractTo");
```

Comment: v4.2 seems support php 7 and 8 too : https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=rar&release=4.2.0